# What does the "Bits per second" option in COM5 Properties tab indicate?

Tags: laptop, internet-connection, port, serial-port

This is related to my Internet's modem. By default Bits per second were set to 7200. I changed it to 128000. Would it affect or increase my internet speed in any way? What do the Bits per second actually mean? Thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: Are you actually connected to the Internet via an analog modem and a phone line?

Comment: @BrianAdkins Not sure if is called "Modem" or "Dongle".It says 3g broadband service on the USB stick.

Comment: Ahhh, in that case, I'd run a speed test at http://speedtest.net .  My guess is that your com port communications settings will not affect your usb 3G speeds.  7200bps is what dial up looked like in 1990.

Comment: @BrianAdkins This is my speedtest result:
http://www.speedtest.net/my-result/2949360601
So coming back to my original question which was what do these bps indicate? How much should the bps look like in 2013?

Comment: That's the baud rate for this interface.  COM5 is clearly labeled the **Diagnostics** interface. So it's not the **primary** interface of the ZTE unit.   Apparently the ZTE unit has more than one interface.  You should probably leave the COM5 baud rate at its default setting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This goes back to the deep dark times when people actually used dial-up/leased modems and serial ports.  There were a number of speeds with which the computer could talk to the modem, and not all modems would recognise all / faster speeds.  In reality, if changing the speed works, this won't make any difference because you are not sending the Internet out over this interface - but if you were, faster speeds would change the speed at which the modem talked to the computer - if the Internet connection were constrained by the speed of communications with the computer it would speed it up, but in most cases it wouldn't.   Certainly if its 7200/9600 baud, speeding it up to 1280000 baud is not a very important change.